# How to control data stored in an array

Tags: c#, arrays

Sorry i want to store specific input data/numbers in an array. In my array i want only the correct numbers to be stored and not the wrong once. I want the proram to continue as long as i have not gotten 4 correct number in my array.
Then i want to print out the total number of array value.
How can I do this in C#? Here is my code:

```
            int min = 5;
            int max = 10;
            int[] array = new int[4];
            int count = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("enter btw 5 och 10");
            int val = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            array[i] = val;

            if (val >= min && val <= max)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Correct, continue...");
                count++;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("wrong, enter btw 5 och 10");
                continue;
            }

            }
            Console.WriteLine(count);
            Console.ReadKey();
}
```

If someone enter e.g 11 or 2, the program will not count it.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: Why an array?  Why not a more-specialized collection type?

Comment: @rory.ap probably an assignment from school

Comment: What's vektor? Maybe it should be array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fungerar det?

```
{    
    var min = 5;
    var max = 10;
    var array = new int[4];
    var count = 0;
    var total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter between 5 and 10:");
        var correct = false;

        while (!correct)
        {
            var val = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (val >= min && val <= max)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Right number...");
                array[i] = val; //Add the value to the array
                count++; //Increase count
                total += val; //Add the value to total
                correct = true; //Break the while loop
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong, enter between 5 and 10:");
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"The total of the values are: {total}");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
int min = 5;
int max = 10;
int[] array = new int[4];
int index = 0;

while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("enter btw 5 och 10");
    int val = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (val >= min && val <= max)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Rätt siffra...");
        array[index] = val;

        if(index >= array.Length-1)
            break;

        index++;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("wrong, enter btw 5 och 10");
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(index);
Console.ReadKey();
```

---

It's even better to use `int.TryParse()`   *(like I would write it)*

```
int min = 5;
int max = 10;
int[] array = new int[4];
int count = 0;

while(true)
{
    int val;

    // read the input
    Console.WriteLine("enter btw 5 och 10");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    // parse it
    if(!int.TryParse(input, out val))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not a valid number");
        continue;
    }

    // check the range
    if (val < min || val > max)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("wrong, enter btw 5 och 10");
        continue;
    }

    // store it.
    Console.WriteLine("Rätt siffra...");
    array[count] = val;

    // are we done?
    if(count== array.Length-1)
        // yes, break the while loop before we increase.
        break;

    // increase array index
    count++;
}

Console.WriteLine(count);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Original question could be improved, adding some integer validation, either `try-catch` or `Int32.TryParse()`

Comment: Thanks for your comment